# Fortify Android checks

Tags: android, fortify

I'm curious about what vulnerabilities the Fortify rulesets look for in Android applications. Unfortunately I'm unable to find any documentation on the same. I know that they look around for Java specific vulns along with Permission checks for Components -- anything else? SQL injection checks? Intent checks?

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides all the regular Java rules, there are Android specific rules for the following categories:

**Code Quality:**
Android Bad Practices - Use of Released Camera
Android Bad Practices - Use of Released SQLite Resource
Android Bad Practices - Use of Released Media Resource
Unreleased Resource - Android Media

**Encapsulation:**
  Insecure Storage - Android External Storage
  System Information Leak

**Input Validation and Representation:**
  Command Injection
  Cross: Site Scripting - Persistent
  Cross: Site Scripting - Poor Validation
  Cross: Site Scripting - Reflected
  Header Manipulation - Cookies
  Log Forging
  Path Manipulation
  Query String Injection - Android Provider
  Resource Injection
  SQL Injection

**Security Features:**
  Access Control - Android Provider
  Access Control - Database
  Android Bad Practices - Missing Broadcaster Permission
  Android Bad Practices - Missing Receiver Permission
  Android Bad Practices - Sticky Broadcast
  Password Management
  Password Management - Empty Password
  Password Management - Hardcoded Password
  Password Management - Null Password
  Password Management - Weak Cryptography
  Privacy Violation
  Privilege Management - Android Location
  Privilege Management - Android Messaging
  Privilege Management - Android Telephony
  Privilege Management - Missing API Permission
  Privilege Management - Missing Content Provider Permission
  Privilege Management - Missing Intent Permission

Answer (score 1):

Here's the offical list of what Fortify has to offer:

- http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/index.html

There's to many to list.